Getting wallet balance and transactions into Google Sheets
I'm trying to get some wallet info into my Google spreadsheet using ImportJSON.
I'm having some progress but not too much, unfortunately.
Not being a coder doesn't help either. :) I believe this can be achieved
with a little bit of scripting...
Any help is greatly appreciated!
I have:
Contract address
Wallet address
I want for each transaction:
Timestamp
TxHash
To/From address
Amount
Amount Fee
Historical price in USD
** I'm looking for these blockchains & tokens**
Ethereum  -  ETH & CSCS
Polygon  -  MATIC & CSDU
Since this is the Ethereum place I get it if Polygon is above and beyond...
Thanx,
Mike

What you want will need a bit of coding to be done. I can help you with the details though.
Also, you can refer this answer here
Here is the script for getting what you want.
Steps:

Set up a basic node.js project.
Get an INFURA_KEY to insert in the code.
Add the following code with the above api keys, contract and wallet addresses in a file and run that file

    const Web3 = require('web3');
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    // Initialize web3 instances for Ethereum and Polygon
    const web3Eth = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID');
    const web3Poly = new Web3('https://polygon-rpc.com/');
    
    // Replace with your contract and wallet addresses
    const contractAddress = 'YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS';
    const walletAddress = 'YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS';
    
    // Function to fetch transaction details
    async function getTransactionDetails(txHash, web3) {
      const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
      const txReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
      const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(tx.blockNumber);
      const timestamp = block.timestamp;
      const gasUsed = txReceipt.gasUsed;
      const gasPrice = tx.gasPrice;
      const fee = Web3.utils.fromWei((gasUsed * gasPrice).toString(), 'ether');
      const value = Web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether');
      
      return {
        timestamp: new Date(timestamp * 1000).toISOString(),
        txHash: tx.hash,
        from: tx.from,
        to: tx.to,
        amount: value,
        fee: fee,
        historicalPriceUSD: await getHistoricalPrice(tx.blockNumber, web3),
      };
    }
    
    // Function to get historical price of ETH/MATIC at a given block number
    async function getHistoricalPrice(blockNumber, web3) {
      const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
      const date = new Date(block.timestamp * 1000);
      const formattedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      const symbol = web3 === web3Eth ? 'ethereum' : 'matic-network';
      const response = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${symbol}/history?date=${formattedDate}`);
      return response.data.market_data.current_price.usd;
    }
    
    // Function to fetch transactions for a given wallet address
    async function fetchTransactions(walletAddress, web3) {
      const transactions = [];
      const latestBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
      const blocksToFetch = 1000; // Adjust this value as needed
    
      for (let i = latestBlock; i > latestBlock - blocksToFetch; i--) {
        const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
        for (const tx of block.transactions) {
          if (tx.from.toLowerCase() === walletAddress.toLowerCase() || tx.to?.toLowerCase() === walletAddress.toLowerCase()) {
            transactions.push(await getTransactionDetails(tx.hash, web3));
          }
        }
      }
    
      return transactions;
    }
    
    // Main function to fetch and print transactions
    async function main() {
      const ethTransactions = await fetchTransactions(walletAddress, web3Eth);
      const polyTransactions = await fetchTransactions(walletAddress, web3Poly);
    
      console.log('Ethereum Transactions:', ethTransactions);
      console.log('Polygon Transactions:', polyTransactions);
    }
    
    main().catch(console.error);


Wow, thank you very much, Sir!
I will have to do some research to get this working. It’s
way more than I expected.
Again, thank you so much.
Cheers,
Mike
